# How to derive the dual problem of this optimization problem with domain limited to $\|y\|_\infty\leq1$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

When I am doing my convex optimization homework, I encountered a problem regarding deriving the dual problem.

Define $\|x\| = \max_{1\leq i_1\leq...\leq i_r}|x_{i_1}| +...+|x_{i_r}|$, then it's plain to see that $\|x\|$ is the optimal value of the optimization problem:$$\max\quad x^Ty$$$$\text{subject to}\quad\|y\|_\infty\leq1, \|y\|_1\leq r$$

Then my teacher says this is equivalent to:
$$\min\quad -x^Ty$$$$\text{subject to}\quad \|y\|_1\leq r$$
with $\textbf{dom} f = \{y | \|y\|_\infty\leq1\}$

My teacher wants me to derive the dual problem $\textbf{exactly}$ in the second form (i.e. let $\textbf{dom} f = \{y | \|y\|_\infty\leq1\}$, instead of an inequality constraint), and use this result to formulate the following problem:
$$\min\quad\|Ax-b\|_2^2+\|x\|$$
as quadratic programming.

So I follow the definition and try to write down the dual function: $L(\lambda) = \inf_{\|y\|_\infty\leq1}(-x^Ty+\lambda(\|y\|_1-r)) = \inf_{\|y\|_\infty\leq1}(-x^Ty+\lambda\|y\|_1)-\lambda r$

Thanks to @nowhere, I think the right way to proceed with this dual function:

$\inf_{\|y\|_\infty\leq1}(-x^Ty+\lambda\|y\|_1) = \inf_{\|y\|_\infty\leq1}(\sum_i -x_iy_i + \lambda|y_i|)$

We can then take the infimum componentwise:

$\inf_{|y|\leq1}(-x_iy_i + \lambda|y_i|) = (\lambda - |x_i|)|y_i|$

$$ =\left\{
\begin{aligned}
0 &\quad |x_i|\leq \lambda \\
\lambda-|x_i| &\quad |x_i|>\lambda
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

but I can't proceed further with the formulation of the Quadratic Programming, so I'm wondering how can I move forward to derive the dual problem and formulate the quadratic programming.Any hints on how can I get this?

Comment: Perhaps,  if $x \leq 1$ then $\sqrt{x}\leq1 $ ??

Comment: @Cardinal: emm I can't get you, can you elaborate on it :)

Comment: I would just write out the components. $-x^T y + \lambda \|y\| = -x_1 y_1 - x_2 y_2 - \dotsb - x_n y_n + \lambda ( |y_1| + |y_2| + \dotsb + |y_n| )$. First, I observe that in order to minimize $-x_i y_i + \lambda |y_i|$, you should choose each $y_i$ to be the same sign as $x_i$ - does that look right?

Comment: Assuming the previous observation was correct, then you reduce the problem to minimizing $-|x_1||y_1| - |x_2||y_2| - \dotsb - |x_n||y_n| + \lambda(|y_1| + |y_2| + \dotsb + |y_n|) = (\lambda - |x_1|)|y_1| + (\lambda - |x_2|) y_2 + \dotsb + (\lambda - |x_n|)|y_n|$, subject to $|y_i| \leq 1, i = 1, \dots, n$. In order to minimize the expression, let $|y_i| = 0$ when $\lambda - |x_i| \geq 0$, and $|y_i| = 1$ when $\lambda - |x_i| < 0$.

Comment: @nowhere: I think this makes sense, but how is this related to the formulation of the following problem into QP?

Comment: @Nego Oh, I didn't think that far ahead. Please give me some more time to think about the next step :)

Comment: @Nego By the way, your question was asked before (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4446343/norm-x-defined-as-the-sum-of-largest-r-absolute-values-how-to-write-m?rq=1), and the person who answered it couldn't do the QP reformulation either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have an idea, but I'm not 100% sure. (I wished to post it as a comment first, but it's too long.) So please take what I say with a grain of salt.

Summarizing what we have so far: The notation $\|x\|$ means $\max_{i_1, \dots, i_r} |x_{i_1}| + \dotsb + |x_{i_r}|$, i.e., sum of the $r$ largest absolute values of $x$. We have shown that
\begin{align*}
-\|x\| & = \min_{\|y\|_\infty \leq 1} -x^T y \quad \text{s.t.} \ \|y\|_1 \leq r
\end{align*}
By strong duality, we get
\begin{align*}
-\|x\| & = \max_{\lambda \geq 0} L(\lambda)\\
& = \max_{\lambda \geq 0} \Big( -\lambda r + \sum_{i = 1}^n \min(0, \lambda - |x_i|) \Big)
\end{align*}
If we flip the sign, we get
\begin{align*}
\|x\| & = \min_{\lambda \geq 0} \Big( \lambda r + \sum_{i = 1}^n \max(0, |x_i| - \lambda) \Big)
\end{align*}
Now let's return to the problem
\begin{align*}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} & \quad \|Ax - b\|_2^2 + \|x\|
\end{align*}
It can be written as
\begin{align*}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} & \quad \Big\{\|Ax - b\|_2^2 + \min_{\lambda \geq 0} \Big( 
\lambda r + \sum_{i = 1}^n \max(0, |x_i| - \lambda) \Big)\Big\}
\end{align*}
That's the same as
\begin{align*}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \lambda \geq 0} & \quad \|Ax - b\|_2^2 + \lambda r + \sum_{i = 1}^n \max(0, |x_i| - \lambda)
\end{align*}
This problem can be reformulated as
\begin{align*}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \lambda \geq 0, s_1, \dots, s_n} & \quad \|Ax - b\|_2^2 + \lambda r + \sum_{i = 1}^n s_i\\
\text{subject to} & \quad \max(0, |x_i| - \lambda) \leq s_i, \quad i = 1, \dots, n
\end{align*}
which is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \lambda \geq 0, s_1, \dots, s_n} & \quad \|Ax - b\|_2^2 + \lambda r + \sum_{i = 1}^n s_i\\
\text{subject to} & \quad 0 \leq s_i,\\
& \quad |x_i| \leq \lambda + s_i, \quad i = 1, \dots, n
\end{align*}
To get rid of the absolute value sign, introduce slack variables $y_1, \dots, y_n$ and write the problem as
\begin{align*}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \lambda \geq 0, s_1, \dots, s_n, y_1, \dots, y_n} & \quad \|Ax - b\|_2^2 + \lambda r + \sum_{i = 1}^n s_i\\
\text{subject to} & \quad 0 \leq s_i,\\
& \quad -y_i \leq x_i \leq y_i,\\
& \quad y_i \leq \lambda + s_i, \quad i = 1, \dots, n
\end{align*}
Now the objective is quadratic, and all constraints are linear.